# Angular deploy on GitHub Pages

Tags: angular, github, deployment, github-pages

I'm trying to deploy an Angular app to GitHub pages but setting the gh-pages branch as the source shows the content of the README file.

I've tried the official way which is:

```
git checkout -b gh-pages
git push origin gh-pages
npm install -g angular-cli-ghpages
ng build --prod --base-href https://[username].github.io/[repo]/
```

After I run ngh I get this message in terminal:

```
User@JoseTurron MINGW64 /i/projekt-zaliczeniowy-cdv (gh-pages)
$ ngh
index.html could not be copied to 404.html. This does not look like an angular-cli project?!
(Hint: are you sure that you have setup the directory correctly?)
Diagnostic info: ENOENT: no such file or directory, stat 'I:\projekt-zaliczeniowy-cdv\dist\index.html'
�‍� Uploading via git, please wait...
� Successfully published via angular-cli-ghpages! Have a nice day!
```

I'm out of ideas on how to solve this. Thanks for any suggestions!

- REPO: https://github.com/JoseTurron/flight-booking-cdv
- GITHUB PAGES: https://joseturron.github.io/flight-booking-cdv/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The solution is as follows:

```
ng add angular-cli-ghpages
ng deploy --base-href=https://[username].github.io/[repo]/ --name=[username] --email=[email]
```

Answer (score 4):

Here is Step by Step Guide How to Deploy the angular app to Github pages.

`1) git init` //for initializing git use cmd/shell hit Enter

`2)git add .` //add all files in git

`3)git commit -m "first commit"` // message for commit

`4)git remote add origin "Your Remote Repository Url"` // connecting to git repo

`5)git push -u origin master` // pushing to git repo

`6)npm install -g angular-cli-pages` //installing angular pages for deploy Angular project on github pages

`7)ng build --prod --base-href="https://Username.github.io/github-Repo/"` //production build ghpages

8*)Goto project folder after above steps completed there will be dist folder go inside dist>YOurProjectFolder-> move all files one level up.*

`9)angular-cli-ghpages` //deploying ghpages

10)goto github repo setting scroll down there will be github pages and link of your publihshed repo click on that and BOOM Angular app is live on ghPages